# C# .NET Fetching and displaying images from database

Tags: c#, .net, database

I am developing an MVC website where a normal user can upload multiple images into the database and then has the ability to fetch them and display them.

So far I manage to display an image but not multiple. in the class i have:

```
string imagedata = Convert.ToBase64String(decryptedBytes);
string imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", imagedata);
ViewBag.ImageData = imageDataURL;
return View();
```

and in the view I have :

```
<img src="@ViewBag.ImageData" height="400" width="500" />.
```

Should I make a type of foreach in the view or in the method itself please?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should avoid using `ViewBag`, and pass the image objects around using `@model`.

I would suggest strongly typing your collection (e.g. `IList<ImageData>`, but for the purposes of the example (Razor CSHTML):

```
@model IList<string>

@foreach (var image in Model)
{
    <img src="@image" ... />
}
```

I'm also going to leave out Model -> ViewModel conversions etc for simplicity.

To get the model from the controller, pass it in the `View()` (assuming you already have imageList populated from the database):

```
IList imageList = GetListOfImages(user.Id)
return View(imageList);
```

Comment: Currently i dont have an image list. Only the db populated. So basically i must store the images from db into a list right?

Comment: Yep - whatever your chosen database access is (I am going to assume Entity Framework) then you'll need to return the list of images from the database. Typically you'd do this with `context.Images.Where(someQuery).ToList()`

Comment: I have this method in the data access layer. Can i use this one instead?
       public IQueryable<Image> GetImages()
       {
            return Entity.Images;
       }

Comment: Yep, that would work, but you'll need to filter the `IQueryable` to the given user and potentially return an `IEnumerable` (seeing as you are only going to iterate over the image collection and display it).